# Difference between Should Be Improved and Unsalvageable in Triage

Tags: discussion, triage

I have recently been given access to the Triage review queue and actively reviewing questions on it.

I am a little confused about when to use "Should be improved" and "unsalvagable".

According to the help box:

> - **Should Be Improved** for questions where edits by the author or others
>     would result in a question that is clear and answerable
> - **Unsalvageable** for questions that cannot or should not be answered and must therefore be removed from the site

In my opinion, apart from blatant spam or off-topic questions, even the worse questions should be marked as 'should be improved' as they would no longer be as bad as they seem if they are edited.

But clicking 'unsalvageable' presents you with the chance to flag a question for the same reasons that I would think it should be improved (for example, not clear what you are asking and too broad), which would then prompt the original poster to improve the question. For me, 99% of bad questions 'should be improved' but usually get flagged for being bad (which you only get if unsalvageable).

I am confused about when to use 'should be improved' and when to use 'unsalvagable'.

Hope that this makes sense (or at the very least is not unsalvageable).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

***Should be improved***

- Contains everything (or almost everything) needed for folks to answer the question
- Could benefit from some edits for clarity, grammar, punctuation, English mistakes, code formatting, etc
- Could really use a better title so that folks can tell what the question is about
- *Might* be missing a few things, but there's enough there to suggest the author could / will fix that if it's pointed out to them politely
- ***A clear on-topic question is present, it just needs some help to be made clearer***

***Unsalvageable***

- Extremely difficult, or nearly impossible to read
- You don't even know where'd you begin to edit
- Could be just completely off-topic (How do I start a software company?)
- Even with a Herculean effort, the question isn't going to be that good
- It's probably easier if the OP just tries again

When you click ***Should Be Improved*** - you'll soon be tasking folks working in a special help & improvement queue to make substantive edits to the question. If you think the question *could* be good if someone spent a little time on it, then indicate that it should be improved.

Don't mistake it with *could* be improved, almost anything *could* be improved, if the question seems fine as it is then just indicate that it looks okay.

If you think the question is not going to be that great even with work, then it's time to click unsalvageable.

Comment: So, in cases where the only person who could improve it is the OP (for example, no code has been supplied, just a problem statement) is "Should be Improved" the correct action? Or should it be flagged "Unclear what you're asking"?

Comment: For what it's worth (feedback), here's how I currently review: "Looks OK" -> not awful, "Should Be Improved" -> awful but not obviously fitting a close reason (usually accompanied by clicking through and downvoting), "Unsalvageable" -> fits a close reason (regardless of possible improvement; that's nominally what "on hold" is for).  Regardless of the design intent, I think we'll have to see real data pitting triage reviews versus question outcomes to see how people _actually_ review.

Comment: @TZHX I can't give a blanket answer to that. It would depend on the overall quality of the question aside from the missing information. If there's obvious effort put into it, then it's probably _very_ likely that if prodded, the OP would add whatever is needed. It really depends on how vested they seem to get an answer on Stack Overflow. It's hard to describe aside from you generally know when you see it.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom We are looking at it, and folks have been _pretty_ accurate so far, at least as determined by the outcome of the question, and lots of spot checking where Josh / I would look at something sorted and compare the action taken with what we'd do. We're keeping an eye on it closely as we look to have triage feed the Help & Improvement queue (the goal obviously making sure nothing but actually salvageable stuff gets in there for the most part).

Comment: Unsalvageable is more about "there's something fundamentally wrong with your question that makes it unfit for our site" than anything else.

Comment: "Should Be Improved for questions where edits _by the author_ or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable" -- this really needs to be removed for the Help & Improvement queue to work properly.  If the author has to add information, the question should be on-holded instead.  (A few skips into H&I taught me I'd been doing it wrong for weeks now, sorry.)

Comment: There are three choices. One is "ok". That leaves two choices. If it's not one then it's the other. Yet you give two lists of criteria. This is fundamentally a wrong approach to partitioning. And the names should be X and not-X. (It's ok to have quick-decision criteria like "this makes it salvageable" and "otherwise this makes it unsalvageable" *then* "otherwise this makes it (un)salvageable".) Moreover the *actual* meaning of "should be improved" is "task folks working in a special help & improvement queue to make substantive edits". So you give two sets of criteria for that choice.

Comment: I just came across the "STOP! Look and Listen." page while reviewing. This page should really link to a meta question like this for clarification. Specifically when supposedly looking at a first question of a user I'd give them quite some leeway to let them come into the culture. I did not understand "Should be improved" means "Can be improved by people other than the author" - agreeing with @JeffreyBosboom about removal of "the author or" from the description. I'd also encourage philipxy's approach to partitioning.