# Triage questions that needs improvement but that need is already pointed out in comments?

Tags: discussion, triage

Sometimes when going through the Triage queue I come across question that absolutely "Should be improved", but where someone has already pointed out the need for improvement in comments.

For instance, a question where OP puts the code on an external site, and someone has commented explaining to the OP that they should include the code in the question.

It needs improvement, so I feel like I should press "Should be Improved".

On the other hand, what more could a moderator do than point out what has already been pointed out? So maybe I should press "Looks OK", even though it does not actually Look OK.

In the end I usually chicken out and press "Skip".

A similar situation is when the question is OK but the formatting horrible. If I edit the formatting, should I then press "Looks good"?

Comment: what kind of improvement? if it's the kind of improvement that should be done by the community, why does it need comments pointing that out? If the OP is the only one that can improve it, clicking should be improved is incorrect.

Comment: In this particular example, I guess the role of the community would be to point out the need to include the code and the role of the user to actually do it. The help box for the Triage queue sais "Should Be Improved for questions where edits **by the author** or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable" (My highlight.)

Comment: Pretty sure that's a common issue with the wording. by that logic, we would never have anything that is unsalvageable, because the author can potentially fix it by adding more information or clarifying the issue.

Comment: Clicking should be improved sends the question over to the help and improvement queue for other users to improve the question. Why would we want to send a question to that queue if it can **only be fixed by the author**?

Comment: There's definitely some disagreement within the community on what types of improvement should be met with the "should be improved" option. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287024/

Comment: Thanks for the link, @KevinB. I guess a question that could be easily fixed if the OP is just giving a polite pointer would benefit from being categorized as "Should be improved". And when that polite pointer is already given, as in the example, I asume there is no need for community intervention anymore. So then do I click "Looks OK"?

Comment: For me, it would depend on whether or not the question in it's current form matches a close reason. If it's missing an error message, or the code to recreate the problem, i would choose unsalvageable with the proper close reason. Not because it's unsalvageable, but because it matches the close reason that i would use if I found the question in the wild.

Comment: Maybe I take the wordings on the buttons to litteraly. Instinctively it feels wrong to click "Unsalvageable" when there is an easy and obvious way to salvage the question (for the OP). But I am more then willing to put my instincts to the side and take advice from someone with more insight here... :-)

Comment: I wouldn't consider myself as having more insight, you likely use the system more than I do! i tend to stay away from the review queues, i prefer to fix/moderate questions directly. It's just important to remember that these are tools, focused on accomplishing a goal. You should always use your best judgement. If the decision was black and white, we wouldn't need a review queue because it could be done with code.

Comment: Questions that should be improved ***by the community*** are eligible for `Should be Improved`,  questions that have some minor errors in formatting and similar are eligible for `Looks OK` and questions that require input from the author of the post are eligible for `Unsalvageable` (which really means `Unsalvageable without input from the author`, but that's too long)

Comment: That is not how I would spontanusly interpret the current instructions (both the help text and the labels of the buttons). But perhaps that is more an issue with me than the text.

Comment: @Anders It's an issue with the text. There have been complaints about it since triage was introduced, but Shog seems to think triage is working well enough anyway.

Comment: Since I am getting quite mixed opinions (both in comments and in answers) on not just my original question, but also the triage queue in general, I don't think I dare accept any of the answers since I'm not sure I dare accept any answer. I do, however, greatly appreciate the input.

Answer (score 6):

If it's practical for Joe Random 2ker to spend fifteen painful minutes whipping the question into shape without any further input from the original querent and get something that's answerable… send it to Help & Improvement by hitting <kbd>Should Be Improved</kbd>! Code on, say, JSFiddle should generally be fine for this; code on some random paste site may or may not be; and code that's just the source grabbed from their website is likely not yours to redistribute on SE, so no. Those need someone to legally authorize under CC-wiki.

On the other hand, if the question just can't really be edited all the way into shape, no one in H&I will be able to do anything with it either, so don't send it there. Hit <kbd>Unsalvageable</kbd> instead … even if the OP can, in principle, edit it to become salvageable, that's not *the community at large* that does the salvaging. <kbd>Unsalvageable</kbd> is for when it's out of our hands.

Answer (score 1):

> It needs improvement, so I feel like I should press "Should be Improved".

Your instincts are correct. It still needs improvement, so that's the right choice.

Don't worry about who can do what with it; the purpose of Triage is simply to sort questions into groups. It may be that the only thing to be done with the question is get rid of it; OTOH, the requested improvement may arrive.

Tim suggested "Must be edited" would be a less opaque name for this category the other day; I'm warming up to the idea.

Comment: this sounds like "should be improved" doesn't care about if the asker is the only person that can improve the question, is that intended? I thought "should be improved" meant "by community"? I think Anders means questions where the asker needs to be the one doing the improvement.

Comment: Does it really matter, @jan? If the question is unanswerable without the edit, it will get the edit or be deleted.

Comment: "Should be improved" sends the question into the h&i queue but the h&i queue doesn't offer the option to close the question

Comment: Not everything that should be improved ends up in the helper queue.

Comment: What are the rules then? I think I'm missing newest information.