# Reopening a "poor" question with a good answer

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, reopen-closed

I am talking about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532063/creating-a-custom-shaped-button-in-wpf) closed question.

While the question doesn't show research effort, nor attempts, it's quite *canonical* (short, clear, and with an image). I doubt adding some attempts will *improve* it. They would improve it **before** the answer was given.

Should it be re-opened?

And I have thoughts about thousands of other questions with attempts: shouldn't the questions be edited afterwards (after they got an answer) to **remove** attempts and to make them more *canonical*: more useful for closing duplicates, for future readers, etc.?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, that question is fine, save for some superficial edits. There is no reason for it to have been closed. The problem was clear and well-defined, *aside* from the fact that it received a good answer and is now an even more useful resource.

It has now been re-opened.

Comment: The problem is what such question asked today would be downvoted ("Please google first") and closed ("Please show what you have tried").

Comment: There's no reason anyone needs to see what the asker has tried. It obviously didn't work, or they wouldn't be asking the question. Resist the temptation to turn this into a "debug my code" for me website. While they are also on-topic, those types of questions are the least interesting and the least generally-useful of all.

Comment: Your approach is totally different to what I observe and learn. Attempt is almost a **must**. Asking very clear question with just screenshot will immediately generate downvotes and comments: "SO is not code-writing service", "What have you tried", etc. An attempt is actually a good thing, it helps to answer and it could provide missing details by itself e.g. show expertise level. The answer can become more broad to "teach OP" if has multiple mistakes in attempt. But after correct (accepted? good?) answer is posted, the attempt is rather to be removed, to make question shorter and easier.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a help desk. We aren't teachers. When you see snarky comments like "What have you tried?" and "SO is not code writing service", please flag them.

Comment: @Sinatr the confusion comes from the "write this very large project for me with these 5 requirements" is completely off-topic.  But some users have turned that into some sort of requirement of showing visible "effort". If you haven't seen it, Shog9 had a really good summary of the problem.  Lots of linked questions and answers here so drill down through all of them: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388588/question-effort-whats-our-line-in-the-sand/388594#388594

Comment: Note that the advice that it is not necessary to show research or attempts is contrary to that expressed in [ask], under both the heading "Introduce the problem before you post any code" ("Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself.") and "Help others reproduce the problem" ("...if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some")

Comment: @HereticMonkey for people troubleshooting bugs or errors, that's exactly right.  But if you don't have code because you don't know how to do *this 1 small task*, then there is no code to post and you don't need to help other reproduce your problem.  for "Help others understand your problem, you left out the first sentence... *"Not all questions benefit from including code..."*

Comment: @psubsee2003 That takes care of the second quote. The first quote, not so much. I see no reason why the OP of that question could not have included "any difficulties that have prevented [them] from solving it [themselves]." Basically, Stack Overflow is becoming a place where you can get your coding done for free. No need to research. No need to attempt. No need to think. Just ask, get answer, copy-paste. I think we're doing a disservice to our industry. Also, I didn't leave it out, it is inherently included with "if your problem is with code you've written,"

Comment: @HereticMonkey If there is no research effort or attempt, there is a big chance that the question is unclear, too broad or a duplicate. All of which can be closed. But if the question is clear, appropriately scoped and has not been asked before, why does it matter? It could very well help others in the future, which is what we're all about. Who would benefit form a failed attempt? Definitely not those 15k people who have viewed the question. It would only add additional fluff you need to search through.

Comment: @HereticMonkey if you are able to boil your question down to a very reasonably scoped problem, then you have done your research.  The user at that point knows (1) that it isn't a duplicate, and (2) they don't know how to solve this small problem.  Questions like the one referenced here are infinitely more valuable and searchable than 45 variations of "what's wrong with my code" that include all of the necessary code.  The latter is what is turning SO into a help desk.  the former is more consistent with the original vision of the site.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the general question though. If a poor question has a excellent answer, should it be reopened as the answer itself adds huge value to the site?

Comment: @TheMaster If a question is bad it should be closed. If the answer is excellent then the Q&A should not be deleted after the closure.

Comment: Answers are what ultimately matter here. If there's a good answer, fix any egregious problems with the question and give thanks for the answer, @TheMaster

Comment: This answer and its comment is revolutionizing what I had understood until now (from both "How to ask" and the imitation of the experienced user) about "too broad" questions. Now I feel confused...

Comment: Just to confirm my confusion, here it is the first triage review I opened this evening: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63119967/which-is-faster-putobject-or-uploadfilelist . Until now it would have been unsalvageable because of the lack of code. It actually scores -2 and a comment asks for OP's tests. OP could have put more effort, indeed, but the question is clear: what function is faster? I skipped it...

Comment: @RobertoCaboni https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308837/make-it-easier-to-close-job-shop-gimme-teh-codez-questions

Comment: @Shog9   Would you like to add that as a answer? So that I may refer others to it as a precedent/consensus.

Comment: @TheMaster Have you seen [the canonical blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)? I'm sure Shog9 has written something like this a half-dozen or more times, but I don't have an encyclopedic memory of his answers. Maybe he does?

Comment: CodyGray Thank you for the links(One thing though. Currently reps are equal for both questions and answers). I'll also search Shog9's  history.

Comment: Here are two for you, @TheMaster: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions/281795#281795) and [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/301064/how-do-i-handle-triage-no-research-cases/302067#302067)