# Failed a review audit, Should be Improved vs. Unsalvageable

Tags: discussion, specific-question, disputed-review-audits

I was reviewing the following question, and felt like with a proper addition of information the post could have been useful. The users problem was the range inputs are not working in IE using a WordPress plugin, however the post is low quality as there is no code (and bad grammar).

Without code, proper grammar and an explanation of what the user tried, the post is bad, however I don't feel it's unsalvageable, if Vishnu followed the advice in the comments, the post could easily be salvaged into a useful post about **why** his particular inputs are not functioning in his application.

I've been trying to increase my ability to review with accuracy, and this one threw me for a loop, why exactly is it unsalvageable?

It becomes clear what he is asking if you read the whole post, even if it is formatted terribly. If only code was added, it would be fine. I feel like while reviewing I run into plenty of questions where code simply needs to be added, and then the question is a useful addition to the site, which falls into Should be Improved as far as I know.

I was following the general sentiment from [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287024/difference-between-should-be-improved-and-unsalvageable-in-triage) post.

[image: Review]

Comment: Duplicate of a post I linked? I agree the question is very similar, but perhaps insight into why this particular question is unsalvageable would help me review more accurately in the future!

Comment: The bullet points in Tim Post's answer explain the difference quite well. Every post can be turned into a good one by deleting what's written and writing a good question from scratch. But when this is the sort of change that's required, the post is Unsalvageable.

Answer (score 6):

That question does not include even close to enough information necessary for an answer.

Because of potential link-rot, links are not taken into consideration; As well, users from the community can not be expected to follow a link and dig through the source code just to make the question on-topic.

If you remove the link, the question is as follows

> hi all in my sites range input not working, i user a plugin for this in Wordpress

This question could be closed for any of the following reasons, and there is no reasonable amount of editing that can be done by the community to make it on-topic and answerable.

- Unclear
- Too broad
- No MCVE

Comment: Taking into account the title, and fixing grammar the question becomes: "All my range inputs are not working in IE. Wordpress plugin is used to create these input elements." That seems to fall under "A clear on-topic question is present, it just needs some help to be made clearer". So if code is missing and the author needs to add code, the question automatically becomes unsalvageable? I feel like that's not how most posts are reviewed, but if it's how it should be, I'll start doing it!

Comment: If it needs input from the OP to be on-topic, then it is unsalvageable.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. This is definitely not how most questions are reviewed, and I'm pretty sure I failed an audit in the opposite direction by marking unsalvageable when the post needed code (and it was Should be Improved apparently), but moving forward I will review by that standard. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Some questions don't need code, debugging questions definitely do. On the other side of that argument, lots of people upvote complete garbage on a regular basis for any number of reasons... And that is how bad audits are made. While bad audits are rare, they definitely do leave a bad taste in your mouth.